# Print Check Box Selected Data only

Tags: php, javascript

Hi i am having results and its contains a checkbox as `<input type='checkbox' name="ChkS[]" value='<? echo $rs->id?>'>`

I have a print out list option in the footer as `<input type="button" value="Show Printable List" class="butten" onClick="openPrint()">`

Its opening the printable list in new pop up window.

```
function openPrint() {
    window.open("<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?<?=$qstring?>&print=true","","width=1024,height=600,menubar=yes,resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes");
}
```

I am in need to use the above select checkbox and it should show the selected print list in the pop up ?

I hope it should not be problem any1 to understand it. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Modification:

```
var s = "";
function changeval(value) {
    s = value;
}
function openPrint() {
    alert(s);
    window.open("<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?<?=$qstring?>&print=true","","width=1024,height=600,menubar=yes,resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes");
}
```

HTML Modification:

```
<input type='checkbox' name="ChkS[]" value='<? echo $rs->id?>' onchange="changeval(this.value)" />
```

What I have done?

1. Created an Global Variable `s`.
2. Attached or Bind `onchange` event on checkbox and set the value of Variable `s` according.
3. Now, You have variable `s` with value, you just have to use it in any function.

Comment: Can not i use something like `function openPrint {
 if(notChecked(document.thisForm.elements["ChkS[]"],"Show Printable List")) {return;}
 document.thisForm.action="view_members.php?Mode=Activate&page="+page+"&membership_type=<?=$_REQUEST['membership_type']?>";
 document.thisForm.submit();
}`

Comment: i didn't get notif of your comment but you accepted my answer. Did you get what you wanted?

Comment: Hi, no still, actually your answer is quite helpfull that why i accept it but still i am engage in same issues. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have defined button onclick event , instead of this set onclick event on 
checkbox.

```
<input type='checkbox' name="ChkS[]" value='<? echo $rs->id?>' onClick="openPrint();">
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Its opening the pop up only select of any checkbox. ANy more help ?

Comment: Ok onclick checkbox it will opening popup box right ? now what you want to do ?

Comment: i want simply to print the selected checkbox value in my printlist. Like if i select 5 out of 10, its should show 5 members list in pop up box which is poped for printing the list